# Unit testing / mocking XML-RPC.net calls

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, xml-rpc

I'm developing an application that uses CookComputing XML-RPC.net

My question is how to unit test methods that call an external rpc method.

If we take the example on the site:

```
//This is the XML rpc Proxy interface
[XmlRpcUrl("http://www.cookcomputing.com/xmlrpcsamples/RPC2.ashx")]
public interface IStateName : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("examples.getStateName")]
    string GetStateName(int stateNumber); 
}


public class MyStateNameService 
{
    public string GetStateName(int stateNumber)
{
        IStateName proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IStateName>();
        return proxy.GetStateName(stateNumber);
     }
}
```

How can we effectively test the result of IStateName without actually hitting 
http://www.cookcomputing.com/xmlrpcsamples/RPC2.ashx

I suppose a good start would be a constructor on `MyStateNameService` taking an IStateName, and passing in a fake (or mocked?) instance on IStateName...

I'm interested in testing it for actual content - for example faking up the response from the endpoint, and returning that somehow, not just verifying that `GetStateName` calls the service...

**Edit**

I'm not trying to test the *content*  of the service as such, moreover what **my** classes do with it.

So, for example, say the response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
        <value><string>My State Name</string></value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I'd want to 'fake' that response some how to test that `MyStateNameService.GetStateName` actually returned 'My State Name'

Comment: Why would you want to test the content? Surely once it's hit the `IStateName` proxy it's no longer the concern of you application. Don't test external code, that's up to whoever wrote the library!

Comment: Sorry... i'll edit the question to make it clearer. Please see edited question

Comment: I'm still not sure about this. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't handle the XML directly, you call a method on the proxy, which creates a request, and sends it to whatever is serving the RPC. The response comes back into the proxy, which then parses the output and gives it to you? In this case you have no control over the XML parsing, the library's proxy class does it, so why would you test it?

Comment: And more, I'm not sure you *could* test it, if you don't have access into the internals of the library...

Comment: Currently, I connect to a live server to test my services. This seems like overkill. Essentially all the server is doing is returning a chunk of XML.
The XML RPC lib is parsing it. So far so good, but i want to test that my classes / structs match the returned xml etc....

Comment: I'll agree that you shouldn't be testing live, but the point of libraries is that you know they work and don't have to test them or write them yourself. I'd never test what an external library does; the closest is to mock their interfaces, like your `IStateName` so you can test *other* classes without them going to the library.

Comment: I don't think you could test the library, without getting the source and figuring out how it processes the XML and hooking into that to test, but I really don't think it's a useful exercise.

Comment: I think we must be getting our wires crossed. I don't want to test xml-rpc.net. I want to test that my class matches up to the response, etc... For example, if a struct of a blog post is returned (title, body, categories[] etc...) it should map to class Blog, with title, body, categories etc... does that make sense?

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I assumed that the mapping was handled by the library, but if you're coding it yourself, it can be tested. In that case, can we have a sample of the service that maps from XML to your POCO?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the Singleton Pattern applied here.

```
XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IStateName>();
```

So your idea with using Dependency Injection (By Constructor) is a good start.
(Do you use an IoC container?)

Next is to create a Mock/Fake/Stub for the `IStateName` service.
This can be achieved by many ways.

- Manual Implementation
- [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/)
- [NMock](http://nmock3.codeplex.com/)
- [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-mocks)
- other automatic/dynamic mocking framework of your choice

Using a dynamic mocking system may save you some work, but you need to learn their usage.

Classic AAA testing example for using NUnit, NSubstitute and a modified `MyStateNameService`:

```
class MyStateNameService
{
  private readonly IStateName _remoteService;
  public MyStateNameService(IStateName remoteService)
  {
    // We use ctor injection to denote the mandatory dependency on a IStateName service
    _remoteService = remoteService;
  }

  public string GetStateName(int stateNumber)
  {
    if(stateNumber < 0) throw new ArgumentException("stateNumber");
    // Do not use singletons, prefer injection of dependencies (may be IoC Container)
    //IStateName proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IStateName>();
    return _remoteService.GetStateName(stateNumber);
  }
}

[TestFixture] class MyStateNameServiceTests
{
  [Test]
  public void SomeTesting()
  {
    // Arrange
    var mockService = Substitute.For<IStateName>();
    mockService.GetStateName(0).Returns("state1");
    mockService.GetStateName(1).Returns("state2");

    var testSubject = new MyStateNameService(mockService);


    // Act
    var result = testSubject.GetStateName(0);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("state1", result);

    // Act
    result = testSubject.GetStateName(1);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("state2", result);

    // Act/Assert
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => testSubject.GetStateName(-1));
    mockService.DidNotReceive().GetStateName(-1);

    /* 
       MyStateNameService does not do much things to test, so this is rather trivial.
       Also different use cases of the testSubject should be their own tests ;) 
    */


  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I know *what* I need to do, just looking for bit more in depth answer here.... I'll probably use moq

Comment: I could give you the code testing the MyStateNameService with NSubstitute, don´t know much about moq though...

Comment: That'd be fine, i'm after concepts mainly, using whatever library. I'm not a 'gimme teh codez' kind of user ;-)

Comment: While writing the example, i noticed that you could be running into Issues due to the fact that you cannot reuse RPC proxies after errors. In this case you would have to inject a ProxyFactoryService, which complicates things a little bit.